# Use Both ISP Public IPs Even IF one is Down In FortiGate FireWall

Tags: firewall, fortigate

I have two IP's Airtel & Sify connected to My Fortigate Firewall.

```
Sify---------->Port1--->163.100.X.X/27
Airtel-------->Port2--->13.26.X.X/27
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I use all public IPs of two ISPs for my server?
2. If one IP address is down, are all Public IPs of both ISPs working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1: You can use all the public IP addresses you got from both ISPs for your server, provided you configure appropriate NAT rules on your firewall.

Ad 2: From your question it looks like you are not running an exterior routing protocol (ie. BGP) on your firewall.
In that case, if the link to one ISP goes down the public IP addresses you got from that ISP will not be reachable anymore.

Comment: Thanks for Suggetion.Iam not runing BGP for that we have requre to run BGP

Comment: Yes, if you want to have a public IP address accessible over two separate ISPs you need to run BGP in order to update the Internet routing tables in case one of the links goes down.